# Greasemonkey - Button Added to a <div> I added, not calling my greasemonkey functions

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button, greasemonkey

So I have a button that I added through GreaseMonkey:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.value = 'Off';
input.onclick = turnTheWheelsofTime;
```

This button worked fine when I added it to the page using this:

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

However, I wanted to position my button in a non-moving box on the page, instead of just appending it to the end (this is my real concern, the following is just how I applied it, so if you know a better way I would be happy to hear)

I found a solution that used AJAX. I added these to my script:

```
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
 // @grant       GM_addStyle`<br><br>
$("body").append ( '\
    <div id="displayBox">\
    <p id="displayBoxText">Test</p>\
    <button id="gmCloseDlgBtn" type="button">Close popup</button>\
    </div>\
' );
```

To add the button to this new `<div>` I created, I got the element and called it box_element, and used this line:

```
box_element.appendChild(input);
```

instead of the previous:

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

This works sort-of perfectly. The box is added to my `<div>`, I didnt paste this in the question but I used some CSS with GM_addStyle, and it all got applied to my `<div>`. Everything looks beautiful, but the button doesn't do anything.

Why? I can have it do a `console.log('test');` which works fine, but when I try to use functions from my Greasemonkey script, nothing happens?

Comment: I dont feel this is relevant to the question, but this is how the gmCloseDlgBtn is worked:
    `//--- Use jQuery to activate the dialog buttons.
    $("#gmCloseDlgBtn").click ( function () {
    $("#displayBox").hide ();
    } );`
This button works fine, but when I try to add my button using this method it also fails. I assume thats because my Greasemonkey functions are out of the scope of the page in the html, which is why Im confused why its not working the way I asked in the question

Comment: fyi, this isn't "Using AJAX", it's just using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone was curious, I figured out the error. It was actually related to introducing the @grant into my script.
My function turnTheWheelsofTime used javascript functions from the page, and apparently using @grant sandboxes everything.
The sandboxing from the @grant is actually what broke the function